# Appcelerator show Photo Gallery and select imagens

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I need to create a way to show in my app the whole photo gallery in the device, then user can select some images, and then create an order with this imagens.

I am trying to use Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery, but in iOS I can only select one image, and I did not have control over the view.

I will attach an similar example.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1T9Z.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcZEQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS you can use the module `tigmimagepicker` from https://github.com/minhnc/tigmimagepicker and for Android have a look at `titanium-android-imagepicker` https://github.com/prashantsaini1/titanium-android-imagepicker

Both support selecting multiple images from the gallery.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Do you know one that works in iOS and Android?

Comment: not that I'm aware of. But just use the modules above and an if-case to make to separate parts for the imagepickers for each platform